# why the function tellg() does not return the good result?

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, ifstream, seekg

I don't understand why my function `tellg()` jumps from 0 to 2 
here is my code:

```
ifstream uploadFile("upload.txt");
 char letter;
    uploadFile.seekg(0);
    cout<<uploadFile.tellg()<<endl;
    while(uploadFile.get(letter))
        cout<<uploadFile.tellg()<<endl;
    return 0;
```

My file contains this line:

```
0 TS1
```

These are the results I expect:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

but I get this:

```
0
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: What's in your `upload.txt` file?  Are you on a platform that treats the two character sequence CRLF as a newline (`'\n'`)?

Comment: At a guess, your `upload.txt` file contains a "\r\n" sequence that is read in as one character (a newline) but is two in the file.

Comment: You need to give more information.  What operating system are you running this program from?  What OS created the file?  Also, inspect the file in a hex editor and confirm what that space is between those characters.  To us, it is just whitespace, but what is it really?

Comment: Easy way to check @Eljay 's suspicion is to change `ifstream uploadFile("upload.txt");` to `ifstream uploadFile("upload.txt", ios::binary);` and read the file without text mode conversions.

Answer (score 2):

Your file `upload.txt` probably starts with a blank line:

```
0 TS1
```

`ifstream` in *text mode* (the default) treats newlines as a single character.
But on Windows a newline consists of two bytes (CRLF, or `\r\n`). So each time a newline is read, the file position is advanced by 2.

You can open a file in [*binary mode*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode):

```
ifstream uploadFile("in.txt", ios::binary);
```

Then `get()` will always read 1 byte at a time, so also `\r` and `\n` characters separately.